# zsh problem counting the number of lines at the end of a pipe in a variable

Tags: shell-script, shell, zsh

I've recently switched from **bash** to **zsh**, and now it seems I'm experiencing my first compatibility issue.
I'm trying to write a shell script that checks exif date and time info in image and video files, and have a problem with this variable:

```
LINES="$(exiftool -CreationDate -CreateDate -DateTimeOriginal -ModifyDate -MediaCreateDate -MediaModifyDate -TrackCreateDate -TrackModifyDate "$filename" | awk -F ': ' '{print $2}' | sort -u | wc -l)"
```

When the piped commands above are entered directly in terminal for a given file, the output is 2 both in **bash** and **zsh**. However, when used in a variable as above, and then the command `echo $LINES` is entered, the output is 2 in **bash**, and 16 in **zsh**.

I wonder what difference **zsh** has here that I'm missing...

Comment: It *may* not be significant, but `LINES` is a *special parameter* in zsh (and a shell variable used internally in bash) - in general, it's best to avoid ALLCAPS names for your own shell variables.

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you so much! I've just tried it naming the variable NR and it worked, and I was trying to figure out if LINES have a special meaning that I didn't know till now, and then I saw your reply. If you like you can enter this as an answer (as it really is) to earn points. ;-)

Comment: Related: [How can I get rows for terminals? (vs. 'echo $COLUMNS')](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/439458)